Consistency and special pleading in absolute truth claims
There are a lot of questions* on this site that are about a statement made in philosophical skepticism that is best summarized with a quote I found on this  Wiki page:

Philosophical skeptics state that "nothing can be known". This has
caused some to ask if nothing can be known then can that statement
itself be known, or is it self-refuting. One very old response to
this problem is academic skepticism: an exception is made for the
skeptic's own statement. This leads to further debate about
consistency and special pleading.

So,

"Nothing can be known."
We make an exception to protect this statement from being self-refuting and a paradox, by inserting a word like "other" or something similar and construct the new statement: "Nothing can be known, other than this."
"This leads to further debate about consistency and special pleading." - the Wiki article says

Can someone please explain why and in what way this leads to further debate as suggested by the Wiki article?

EDIT:
Possible conclusions:
1.
Can the ultimate conclusion be: "I can't know anything for certain, not even this."? Some sort of fallibilism. I don't think that it is prone to any paradox and it seems to hold steady.
2.
The effort to create, or refute a worldview being baseable on analytic foundations, will always breaks down under self-incoherence of the foundations of logic.

*Just for completeness and clarifying the context; questions regarding this topic in philosophical skepticism:
Is "all truth is relative" an absolute truth?
relativism and russell's paradox
Question about absoluteness
The absolute truth paradox
If we don't know anything for certain, how do we know that?
I think this question is different from the ones listed above because it is about step 3. and all of the questions above are lingering around step 2.

Skepticism can be taken to mean a question rather than an affirmative position. The question is “how do you know what you know?” If the question can’t be answered, all that means is that it hasn’t been answered. Perhaps the answer is sufficient (and thus the skeptic doesn’t have to know that his position is correct), but how does the proponent of that knowledge justify that?

It is a bad start when before even arguing for a claim it can be immediately pointed out that it is incoherent. 'Fixing' still unargued claim by an ad hoc self-exemption is an even worse follow-up. One now not only has to back up the claim but in a way that also justifies exempting it. Without that such special pleading is a fallacy. Being stuck between inconsistency and fallacy is an unenviable dilemma, hence "further debate". Although it is probably best to start over with something more defensible to begin with instead of 'fixing' it.

This question was closed as a duplicate of https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49501/question-about-absoluteness . I am reopening because it is objectively not a duplicate of that question; the other question is about "absolute" vs "relative" truth, and this question is about fallibilism, a different topic. Whether a claim is uncertain is a different topic from whether it is relative.

It is simply "world playing"... The skeptical says: "WE HAVE NO CERTAINTIES" ... but this is a certainty! No, it is not, because we HAVE certainties: we are living, I'm a man, my bank account is X dollars, and so on. IF we want that the discussion has some (limited) philosophical interest, we have to consider the right context. Scientific knowledge: it is at the same time effective and revisable. How this is possible? Mathematics is certain: but some axioms and rules of logic has been revised. A lot of "big issues" are still answered: how to make progress in philosophy?

The resolution is to use a sentence S such as, "Nothing can be known with perfect certainty."
Then we interpret the word "belief" to mean having a credence in a proposition above some context-dependent threshold, such as 0.9 or 0.999.
Knowledge is when we have credence in a proposition above some context-dependent threshold, and also a "good-enough" justification for that credence that (critically) doesn't rely on any false assumptions, and also the proposition happens to be true.
So we both believe, and know S, but only at some level of credence, such as 0.9999. We do not believe or know S with perfect certainty, so there is no self-referential paradox; S does not contradict itself.

This doesn’t get around the problem. One can ask: how do you know that you have a 0.99 credence in a proposition rather than 0.98? And what does this mean? Arguably, attaching figures to uncertainty implies attaching knowledge to uncertainty, but that’s the real contradiction

Which is why science uses the word theory despite the flack it gets from people who think it indicates significant doubt. What it does indicate is that science reserves the right to make and correct mistakes, and to further refine answers that turn out to be incomplete. As noted elsewhere, there is no way to prove that we have stumbled upon a Truth about the real world (as opposed to formal structures like mathematics); we can only continue to test the theory against new data, and adjust our confidence in it appropriately. Unfortunately, some don't appreciate that intellectual honesty.

Syed: Science's definition of sufficient confidence to be worth publishing as interesting is six sigma. Personal definitions of when it crosses the additional barrier from theory to belief are unavoidably up to the individual. See previous comment.

@Syed It's not necessary to know that you have 0.99 credence, to have 0.99 credence. What it means is that the complicated machine of your mind can be (relatively) accurately mapped to a model in which propositions are tagged with credence numbers, and that one particular proposition is tagged with the number 0.99 in that model. Self-referential capabilities of the model are optional.

Nice, so I was trying to prove that we can't know anything, but it turns out that we can't even know that... What a world. But +1 for the answer.

Is this answer you presented a part of fallibilism?

@User198 Yes. I have a longer answer about that: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81795/is-there-any-counterexample-given-against-radical-skepticism/81797#81797

I read your longer answer. So just so I can clarify it for my self. We can't be sure about anything, and that also holds for this statement also. So it seems like we are stuck in some kind of limbus where nothing is certain and not even that claim that "nothing is certain" is really certain.

So we can only say: "We are not sure in anything 100%, (we can only be sure about something say 99%), because there must always be some room for changing (correcting) our views". Is that the gist of fallibilism?

If one believed one knew nothing, it would be hard for one to think...
... lacking knowledge of concepts and abstractions and logic and reasoning...
... lacking knowledge of inference, and deduction and induction...
... lacking knowledge of reconciliation, coherence, sympatico.
If one believed one knew nothing of any of such things...
... from where comes the sureness one can speak for others who do have knowledge of such things.
I can understand when an individual claims to be confused and personally underinformed.  I do not understand when they attempt to cast such upon others.  "We" can know nothing?  Pah.  Define "we"?
Except... if one knows nothing... one cannot define "we".

For myself the simple tests are:
#1.  Which of the "known" languages, is one claiming to know nothing in?
#2.  I know with 0% doubt that the Earth (among it many shapes), is predominantly and primarily, physically, a very very slightly oblate sphere.  (I don't entertain dissent on the point).

Philosophy = the study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence, especially when considered as an academic discipline.
If one claims nothing can be known... why would one be bothering to attempt to know?
It is not a very useful line of reasoning or inquiry.
Compare levels of knowledge between a rock, a tree, a baby, and an adult.
If nothing can be known... then there is no difference in the knowledge known by the rock. or the tree, or the baby, or the adult.
